# cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 662 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

When i am trying to run my website (with aspx) this problem comes up:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The database
>   'C:\USERS\XXXX\DESKTOP\BERMAN\APP_DATA\DATABASE.MDF' cannot be opened
>   because it is version 706. This server supports version 662 and
>   earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
>
> Could not open new database
>   'C:\USERS\XXXX\DESKTOP\BERMAN\APP_DATA\DATABASE.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE
>   is aborted.
>
> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file
>   C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Berman\app_data\DataBase.mdf failed. A database
>   with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it
>   is located on UNC share.

What to do?

Comment: If you have a SqlServer 2012 Database don't try to open it with SqlServer 2008 take at least 2012.

Comment: And where can i download it?

Comment: @Eyalse from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain How to change the settings in the VS to support the SQL Server 2012 after i downloaded?

Comment: @Eyalse You don't need to change any settings, just when you install the new version tell it to upgrade the existing version already installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the `Database.mdf` file was created with a later version of SQL Server Express (2012) than the one installed on the server (2008). Upgrade the server with the latest version of SQL Server Express.

Comment: How to change the settings in the VS to support the SQL Server 2012 after i downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re trying to attach to a local db use LocalDb (since vs2012, sql2012), ie:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename= (etc)
```