# upgrading from SQL 2005 instance to 2012 Connection issue ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

HI I am using visual Studio 2012 after upgrading the database to use it with my project inside visual studio 2012 its show me this problem when running the project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this on your dev machine or your production server?

It seems your SQL Server Express is too old possibly. See this StackOverflow question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890891/cannot-be-opened-because-it-is-version-706-this-server-supports-version-662-and).